# Is there a name for functions having this property :$f(f(x))$ = $x$

Tags: functions, soft-question, definition

Not all functions satisfy : $f (f(x)) =x $ for all $x$. .

For example, function $g$ such that $g(x)=x^2$ certainly don't.

For $g(g(x)=g(x^2)=(x^2)^2$=$x^4$ which is not equal to $x$ for all $x$, far from this.

Functions $h(x)=\frac {1} {x}$  ( provided $x$ is not 0) and $h(x)= -x$ do satisfy the property.

Has this property been given a name?

Comment: They are called [involutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involution_(mathematics)).

Comment: @flan That's an answer; you should write it as an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: I also wouldn't be at all surprised to see it called an action of $\mathbb{Z} / 2 \mathbb{Z}$ on a set - though "involution" is certainly the standard terminology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions with this property are called [involutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involution_(mathematics)) or [self-inverse functions](https://www.google.com/search?q=self%20inverse%20function&tbm=bks).

When a function is regarded as a relation, the functions satisfying $f(f(x)) = x$ are exactly the functions which are [symmetric relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_relation). But they are (to my knowledge) never called "symmetric functions".

Answer (score 1):

Functions with this property are known as involutions. Another example of an involution is the map $x \mapsto \frac{x}{x-1}$.

Comment: My apologies for a mistake in my comment earlier.  However, to add to your answer, all nonidentity involutions on $\hat{\mathbb{R}}$ of the form $x\mapsto \frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$, where $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}$, must satisfy $d=-a$ and $a^2+bc\neq 0$.  Thus, involutions on $\hat{\mathbb{R}}$ of the form $x\mapsto \frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$ are $x\mapsto x$, $x\mapsto \frac{\lambda}{x}$ with $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$, and $x\mapsto \frac{x+\beta}{\gamma x-1}$ where $\beta,\gamma\in\mathbb{R}$ are such that $\beta\gamma\neq -1$.